# Most repeating element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I'm trying to make a function that finds the most repeating element in a list. I thought to iterate through the list, check the count of each element and compare them(using 2 variables `numnum` and `numnum2`)

Something's wrong, it always prints 6.

```
l1 = [1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 3, 6, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6]

print(l1)


def mostrepeating(list1=None):
    if list1 is None:
        print('No list was received in the function.')
    else:
        numnum, numnum2, result = 0, 0, 0
        for num in list1:
            if list1.index(num) == 0:
                numnum = list1.count(num)
                result = num
            else:
                numnum2 = list1.count(num)
                if numnum2 > numnum:
                    result = num
                    numnum = numnum2
        print(result)


mostrepeating(l1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `if list1.index(num) == 0`, it resets `results` to 1, loosing the previous count. Remove it and set `result` to the first item in the list. To reduce iterations you should also iterate over `set` of the numbers

```
def mostrepeating(list1=None):
    if list1 is None:
        print('No list was received in the function.')
    else:
        numnum, numnum2, result = 0, 0, 0
        s = set(l1)
        result = list1[0]
        for num in s:
            numnum2 = list1.count(num)
            if numnum2 > numnum:
                result = num
                numnum = numnum2
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 3, 6, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]

appear_dict = {}
for n in l1:
    appear_dict[n] = appear_dict.get(n, 0) + 1

most_repeat = l1[0]
for key, val in appear_dict.items():
    most_repeat = key if val > most_repeat else most_repeat

print(most_repeat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Counter class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the collections module.

```py
>>> l1 = [1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 3, 6, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(l1).most_common(1)[0][0]
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function wich counts all numbers in a list and puts them in a dict.

Input:

> count_elements([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 1])

Output:

> {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}

Code:

```
def add_element_to_dict(dictin, key):
    dictout = dictin
    if key in dictout.keys():
        dictout[key] = dictout[key] + 1
    else:
        dictout[key] = 1
    return dictout

def count_elements(list1=None):
    if list1 == None:
        print("No list specified")
        return
    else:
        numbersdict = {}
        for ele in list1:
            numbersdict = add_element_to_dict(numbersdict, ele)
    return numbersdict
```